# Может ли известное ругательство с упоминанием матери быть сохранившимся аористом 1 л. ед. ч.?

Tags: глаголы, история-языка, мат

У глаголов с основой на согласный формы аориста 1 л. ед. ч. (*несъ*, *везъ* и т.п.) совпадают с их прошедшим временем ед. ч. м. р. в современном русском. (Которое, разумеется, возникло гораздо позже с утратой конечного *-л*.)

Ввиду этого возникает любопытный вопрос о возрасте выражения `еб твою мать`: может ли это быть сохранившийся аорист? В сущности, нельзя даже сказать, что сейчас глагольная форма однозначно интерпретируется как прошедшее — а не, скажем, междометный глагол типа *хлоп* или *прыг*.

Искать что-то на эту тему — дело неблагодарное, учитывая, сколько придется продираться через спекуляции и апокрифы (вроде малоубедительного "пса", который там якобы изначально был субъектом).

Comment: Ну так ведь глагольные междометия образуются усечением от инфинитива, а здесь явно не тот случай. По-моему, тут других вариантов кроме прошедшего времени и нет.

Comment: @user4419802 Другой вариант я привел в самом начале этого вопроса.  Впрочем, аорист тоже прошедшее время.

Comment: А вообще, аорист от "нести" - это же "несохъ", а "несъ" - это причастие? Глянул в книжку - вроде как "нес" - это архаический аорист. Может ли от такой формы что-нибудь остаться?

Comment: @user4419802 Да, вот это серьезно. Насколько архаический? А "несъ" — это и причастие, безусловно, но оно восходит к "неслъ".

Comment: Навряд ли сохранились такие источники, в которых слово "ети" встречается часто. Но в принципе-то должно быть "етехъ", "ете" и причастие "етый". Где и когда там могла "выскочить" форма на "-б" до современного состояния языка - не понятно.

Comment: @user4419802 В "етехъ" не верю, явно же *ети* < *ебти*. *Ебох* тогда скорее.

Comment: Вообще, происхождение всех этих "прыг-скоков", насколько можно понять, считается дискуссионным. "Ёб", похоже, из этой же серии. Версия, что всё это краткий аорист вполне себе жизнеспособна. Но что здесь смущает, так это то, что это как раз самая старая форма аориста.

Comment: @NikolayErshov: old aorist from **ѣбти* (should we acknowledge its existence) would give **ѣсъ*: *jěbsъ > *jěpsъ > *jēsъ, through devocalization and stop-sibilant merge due to the law of rising sonority.

Comment: @Quassnoi Thank you! I appreciate a good debunk as much as I would some auspicious evidence. Could you perhaps turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old aorist from **ѣбти* (should we acknowledge its existence) would give **ѣсъ*: **jěbsъ* > **jěpsъ* > **jēsъ*, through devocalization and stop-sibilant merge due to the law of rising sonority.

Comment: It's true. but, I didn't understand, why yore reconstruction is "*ѣбти". Genersally these form is "ѣбсти", isn't it?

Comment: @behemothus: reconstruction up to where? *с* in words like *грести* and *клясть* is a Russian innovation. _*jebti_ as a possible Proto-Slavic reconstruction is mentioned in *Этимологический словарь славянских языков*.

Comment: Sure, but hypotetical old-russian aorist  "ѣб"  cannot be born in Proto-Slavic era. These form shold be produced from russian "ѣбсти", not from Proto Slavic "*ebti"(?)

Comment: @behemothus: The form you're talking about is simple (asigmatic) aorist. It is a very archaic form. It's not attested in any Russian text (or even Cyrillic text at all, for that matter), only in earliest Glagolitic manuscripts like Zograf Codex. Neither it is attested for any verbs with *ѣ* in the root. The form I'm talking about is old (sigmatic) aorist, which is attested and used in Russian and Church Slavonic, but never for thematic verbs (those with stem ending in a vowel). There is number of idiomatic exceptions (*рехъ* ~ *рекохъ*) which persist from OCS, but that's all.

Comment: Послушайте, мне, наверное, разговорного английского не хватает, двадцать лет без живой практики... Я понимаю, что такое аорист - и откуда он взялся, пусть и в общих чертах.. Сомнения в том, что если брать за основу *ebti, то аорист этот должен был быть унасьедован с таких древнейших времен, откуда и корневые-то морфы доходят в штучном выражении. Это ж все равно, что напрямую  из ПИЕ всю слововорму выводить. А вот если ситать, что это уже **русский** аорист, а не какой-то там четвертый или пятый срнскритский, но за начальную форму надо брать инфинитив "hбсти". т.е. чисто методическое замечание.

Comment: @behemothus: to put the things simply, neither _*ѣбъ_ nor _*ѣcъ_ could have emerged in Russian. Those aorist forms were not productive by the time words like *грести* or *клясть* (and your suggested _*ѣбсти_) would have emerged.

Comment: @behemothus: we try to use English in discussions here. This site is aimed at English speakers and a person which general linguistic interest in Russian but lack of ability to speak might find it hard to read discussions in Russian.

Comment: I see. I thoght you didn't understand my English, but really - my Russian. )))

Comment: I just said, that you answer about proto-slavic "*ebsti" can't be accsepted by me. The form "eб" can't be so old to be proto-slavic. And in Russian it has been produced from **Russain** "hбсти". That's all. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю.
В принципе можно сделать любые предположения. Но зачем здесь аорист? Грамматика непонятна совершенно. 
Что может значить аорист вообще? Законченное однократное действие в прошлом. В прошлом - понятно. А вот почему законченное, да еще однократное.

Ну или вот.

> Иначе аорист можно определить как абсолютное прошедшее
>   повествовательное время, специфика которого заключается в передаче
>   динамичных, активных событий прошлого, не связанных с настоящим
>   временем.

Тоже не катит как-то...

Уточняю, вопросы не "риторические". Это рассуждения. Я не вижу грамматической и/или контекстной причины употреблять такое выражение в форме аориста. *Аорист здесь не по ситуации*. Может, конечно я и не прав. Но мне такой довод кажется достаточно весомым.

Ну это помимо того, что реконструкция формы, как верно пишет Quassnoi в таком виде весьма сомнительна.

Comment: "Не думаю. В принципе можно сделать любые предположения. Тоже не катит как-то, бла-бла-бла" -  To sum it up.. "I have nothing useful to say, but I'll post my answer anyway". Tsk tsk :)

Comment: Не нужно засорять ресурс абстрактными рассуждениями на тему. Перед тем как писать что-то подумайте, есть ли польза от вашего ответа для того, кто его задает.

Comment: @SergZ. практика показала, что конструктивнее оставлять комменты типа "Задаунвоутил потому что...Этот вопрос был бы лучше, если бы..."

Будьте терпимей к новичкам ;)

Comment: Для человека это будет полезным уроком.. Он не новичок.. :)

Comment: shabunc, спасибо, но я не считаю себя новичком. Хотя в целом вы правы. От Serg Z. хотелось бы уже какого-то конструктива. А что вы-то скажете насчет моего тезиса? Он действительно слищком абстрактен для таких "опытных" участников?

Comment: Not my downvote, but as it stands it's hardly an answer, too many rhetorical questions. "It could not be an aorist because aorist had a different grammatical function" - that would be an answer alright (correct or not is another issue).

Comment: ОК, Quaaanoi, thnx, I made some adjustments about "rhetorical quoestions". I hope, my answer became clearer.

Comment: @SergZ. возражение вполне осмысленное и по теме, а вот вы занимаетесь самоцельным шельмованием. И вот эту тенденцию стоит как раз изживать. Я здесь тоже столкнулся когда-то с хамством с порога.

Comment: Nikolay Ershov, спасиб. Не за отповедь. Хамство - вопрос спорный, да и не боюсь я его. Не акцентируйте. А вот что "возражение осмысленное" по теме - это уже кошерно. А то призадумался, куда я попал ))))